# How to add a customer community user into salesforce public group

Tags: community

Am trying to create a public group in salesforce , when am adding the all customer portal user into one group, and then i saved it , after when i click on view users in the group which i have created just now , am not able to find the customer user in these group ,

Note : all these customer user use license type "Customer Community Login"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think this will help you..

Limitations

• You can’t include high-volume community users in:
 ◊ Personal groups or public groups.

◊ Sharing rules.

• High-volume community users can’t manually share records they own or have access to.

• You can’t transfer cases from non-high-volume community users to high-volume community users.

• High-volume community users can’t own accounts.

• You can’t add case teams to cases owned by high-volume community users.

Setting Up Your First Community Granting High-Volume Community Users Access to Records

**Characteristics of High-volume community users:**

• Are contacts enabled to access a community.

• Are assigned to the Customer Community, High Volume Customer Portal, or Authenticated Website license.

• Only share the records they own with Salesforce users in sharing groups.

Comment: Does this mean that Customer Community Login can't be able to be in groups

Comment: According to document this  http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old post but providing info for the people who are still looking around for a solution.
Try adding "All Customer Portal Users" to the public group. It worked for me. I can see all Customer Community users in the group as members.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5) states clearly: you can’t include high-volume users in personal groups or public groups. Customer Community license considered high-volume.

Comment: This is completely wrong, you cannot even add a Customer Community user (not community plus user) to Public Group.